# AWS not giving advertised ram

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two t3.micro AWS instances. One is in us-east-1a and the other is in us-east-1b. Each of the machines should have 1GB of ram. On the first box in us-east-1a I see:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-32 ~]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            663         392          78          24         192         118
Swap:          4095         704        3391
[root@ip-10-0-0-32 ~]#
```

and on the box in us-east-1b I see

```
Swap:             0           0           0
[root@ip-10-0-1-32 ~]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            780         516          72          80         191          71
Swap:             0           0           0
[root@ip-10-0-1-32 ~]#
```

As per https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/ I should getting 1GB of ram. Can anyone explain why I am getting less and why two instances are exactly the same have different amounts of ram?

Comment: Interesting. Can you please edit your question to add the output of "grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo". On my t3a.nano it reports 474360 and on my t3a.micro it reports 980360

Comment: a10: MemTotal:         679552 kB
a11: MemTotal:         799276 kB
I wonder if there is something in the fine print.

Comment: I suspect AWS gives what they say they do, there will be some technical reason. Hopefully someone can answer, if not I could ask AWS support in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the answer I got from AWS. The question then becomes what I can do, to lower the Kernels foot print.

Warm Greetings from AWS Premium Support!!

My name is Prasanth from EC2 Linux team and I am glad to assist you on this case.

Foremost, we’re sorry for the delayed response. We've recently experienced a high influx of customer support cases and are doing our best to respond to each issue at the earliest. Thank you for your patience , I shall proceed to assist you with your concerns.

From the case description, I understand that you have query on why t3.micro memory are actually different at OS level whereas in AWS instance type documents they are listed as 1 GiB. Also you wanted to know why exact same instance type one has 120 MB more ram then the other. Thus you have requested our insight after you observed a difference in the memory available. Please correct me if I have misunderstood your concern in anyway.

Please allow me to answer you queries one by one in the following correspondence.

=> Query 1:- Is there any reason why I am not getting the full 1GB of memory per instance?

Before we proceed further I would like you to inform you that this is an expected behavior. The discrepancy is in memory the kernel reserves for itself (and memory reserved by drivers). This often is a sliding scale based on how much memory is present.

This is due to the fact that kernel may reserve some memory for kernel space and memory management. This can mean that the output of commands such as top and free might not be as detailed in reporting how much memory your system has. The kernel reserves some amount of memory (proportional to its total size) at the startup for a memory tables (for virtual-to-physical addresses translation). This memory given to the memory tables cannot be used by anything else and is subtracted from the total memory size reported. The bigger physical RAM size is, the smaller is the ratio of the memory which cannot be used to the total physical RAM size, the overhead is between 1.56% to 2% for higher memory instances.

Those reserved memory bytes are committed to variable memory reservations. These allocations will generally be the same on a given system, but can vary between systems, or with different kernel images. Their size depends on something external to the kernel like the number of CPUs in the system or the amount of memory, and they're not reclaimable. Mostly, the memory accounted as 'reserved' is committed to mem_map, memory cgroup structures, Kernel hash tables, and Architecture-specific reservations.

You can check the reserved memory information from the dmesg or system logs and you would see similar the Kernel : Memory logs

$ sudo dmesg | grep -i memory

or

$ sudo cat /var/log/messages |grep -i memory

To debug this further, I have launched a similar instance type t3.micro with same AMI (ami-0d6e9a57f6259ba3a) which you used.

```
[root@test1 ~]# cat /etc/system-release
CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)
```

Then I have checked the total available memory through free and /proc/meminfo file and I noticed the memory available is around 790 MB.

```
[root@test1 ~]#  free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            790         161         259          10         369         496
Swap:             0           0           0
[root@test1 ~]#

[root@test1 ~]# grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         809644 kB
```

As mentioned, In the "sudo dmesg | grep -i memory" on the instance and we'll see something like the following:-

```
[root@test1 ~]# sudo dmesg | grep -i memory
[    0.000000] kexec: Reserving the low 1M of memory for crashkernel
[    0.000000] Reserving 160MB of memory at 624MB for crashkernel (System RAM: 995MB)
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0009f000-0x0009ffff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000effff]
[    0.000000] PM: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000f0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.000000] Memory: 261120K/1019488K available (12292K kernel code, 2151K rwdata, 3848K rodata, 2404K init, 6476K bss, 268068K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.026279] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 32K
[    0.047046] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
[    0.724714] Freeing initrd memory: 51480K
[    0.868145] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[    1.004205] Freeing unused decrypted memory: 2040K
[    1.005900] Freeing unused kernel memory: 2404K
[    1.011944] Freeing unused kernel memory: 2020K
[    1.013098] Freeing unused kernel memory: 248K
```

From the output of this you can get the reserved memory, but that may vary depending on the OS and the kernel as well.

Converting this 268068 KB to MB, hence the value is MB is 261.78MB

So, the total memory for the t3.micro instance is ( 790 + 261.78 =  1051) ~ 1 GiB, as we stated in the official documentation. However, as explained above, around 268068 KB are reserved by the Linux kernel in my test instance.

Thus, AWS hypervisor is allocating correct memory resources to guest operating system, since guest operating system reserve some memory spaces for its maintenance and management purposes the PROC file system or memory monitoring tools reported less available memory.

=> Query 2:- Why is it that for the exact same instance one has 120MB more ram then the other.

Memory reserved values may vary depending on the kernel and configuration parameters.

Still later in the boot process, some memory is freed - for example, the initrd ramdisk. So, it fluctuates - The total values heavily depend on the particular system, kernel config and other OS parameters.

The reserved structures scale up with the hardware memory. Some of this is reserved space for bookkeeping, others for driver-allocated memory.

The kernel documentation for /proc says this about meminfo's MemTotal value:

```
MemTotal: Total usable ram (i.e. physical ram minus a few reserved bits and the kernel binary code)

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt
```

Having said that, there's no clean way to predict the total memory available in general.

However, you can find the total allocated memory for the instance with the help of lsmem command. Please find the below output from my test machine for reference.

```
[root@test1 ~]# lsmem
RANGE                                 SIZE  STATE REMOVABLE BLOCK
0x0000000000000000-0x000000003fffffff   1G online        no   0-7

Memory block size:       128M
Total online memory:       1G     <====>
Total offline memory:      0B
```

I hope the above information helps to address your concern. Should you have any further queries regarding this issue or if you feel I have not clarified anything, please feel free to write back for any further questions or additional information. I will be happy to assist you.

Have a great day ahead and stay safe!!

We value your feedback. Please share your experience by rating this correspondence using the AWS Support Center link at the end of this correspondence. Each correspondence can also be rated by selecting the stars in top right corner of each correspondence within the AWS Support Center.

Best regards,
Prasanth R.
Amazon Web Services